# How to get records in mysql where first letter equals 'X', when dealing with spanish characters?

Tags: mysql, collation

As an example:

```
select *
from recording as r
where left(r.title, 1) = 'p'
```

This picks all the recordings where the recording title starts with the letter **p**. I can use other letters...

But, the problem is that i'm dealing with a spanish table that contains recordings like **¿-Por qué?** or **«Por un amor»** o even **¡..Pon la mesa!**, etc... And i do want those recordings to be part of my result set.

How do i get the recordings that start with a specific letter only?

Do i need to create a separate column in the table, let's call it 'sort name', and insert the recording title with all of those special characters stripped out? Are they other solutions, special functions that i'm not aware of in mysql?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysql regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM recording WHERE title REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]*[pP]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL LIKE wildcard '_' this way :

```
SELECT * FROM recording AS r WHERE r.title LIKE '_P%'
```

It will accept any character before the P letter. (And only one character)

If you don't wan't to match words such as 'Ap...', you could use the SQL regex function (Google it, it's quite well documented), or check it afterward using PhP if the case is rare enough.

Edit : Ok, so you want to match titles with several special characters behind the first letter.
In that case, using the regexp function (SQL side or PhP side, depends on your needs) should be the best way